# database for the structure of groups

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for a database where I can look up the structure of any small
 group (lets say to order 100). I know that SAGE has such a database, but 4-7
 Gigabyte-downloads definitely take to long with my modem. Does anyone know
 an online database for the groups ?

Comment: Don't you have access to that using the online front-end to SAGE?

Comment: You candownload GAP, which is a rather smaller download, too.

Comment: Mariano : How big is this file ?

Comment: Peter, is this really the forth account you've created, besides [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79589/peter), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79596/peter) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/79650/peter) one? You are not Agent Smith, aren't you?

Comment: draks : If so, then it was not wanted. It seems to be

Comment: difficult to manage this forum correctly ...

Comment: Perhaps someone can put them together, and if not, I am

Comment: not guilty that it does not work

Comment: hmm, as already mentioned you can ask here if you want them to be merged: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: Can I merge as a guest ? (I have no password)

Comment: oh, ok... why not joining Mathematics.SE? You seem to have some questions...I'm still interested how you got [1005693665747024080598971](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/403574/19341)...

Comment: @Peter: if the library of small groups is available in Sage, then it is because Sage distribution contains a subset of a GAP distribution. You will need to further configure it installing an optional package "database_gap-...", see http://www.sagemath.org/packages/optional/. I agree with the advices to use GAP directly.

Comment: @Peter: also, it's interesting what do you mean by "look up the structure" - is it retrieving a group from the library and exploring its properties, or, given a finite group (of an appropriate order), find its library number (see `?IdGroup` in GAP). [The Small Groups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html) will help you in both situations.

Answer (score 5):

As @Mariano suggested correctly, you can download [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), and then you will have:

> **48.7 Small Groups**
>
> The Small Groups library gives access to all groups of certain ``small'' orders. The >groups are sorted by their orders and they are listed up to isomorphism; that is, for >each of the available orders a complete and irredundant list of isomorphism type >representatives of groups is given. Currently, the library contains the following groups:
>
> those of order at most 2000 except 1024   (423  164  062 groups);
> those of cubefree order at most 50 000   (395   703 groups);
> those of order pn for n ≤ 6 and all primes p
> those of order qn ·p for qn dividing 28, 36, 55 or 74 and all primes p with p ≠ q;
> those of squarefree order;
> those whose order factorises into at most 3 primes.

And some useful codes:

```
SmallGroup( order, i ) F 

SmallGroup( [order, i] ) F
```

> which returns the i-th group of order order in the catalogue.

```
AllSmallGroups( arg ) F
```

> which returns all groups with certain properties as specified by arg. And many othe useful codes.

The following examples are noted here fram GAP manual.

```
gap> G := SmallGroup( 768, 1000000 );
                    <pc group of size 768 with 9 generators>
gap> G := SmallGroup( [768, 1000000] );
                     <pc group of size 768 with 9 generators>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like these one:

- [Groupprops, The Group Properties Wiki](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [MAGMA Online Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)

Comment: MAGMA is also proposed as [Community Promotion Ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6967/19341)...